# Counting even numbers

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

So I input 7 I should only get 0 2 4 6, I thought by cmp[num], num but that doesn't work. I thought of using mov bl [num] cmp al, bl but that doesn't work either

```
section .data

    
section .bss
    num resb 1
    display resb 2

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    
    mov eax, 3 
    mov ebx, 0  
    mov ecx, num
    mov edx, 1

   
print:    
   
   
    mov al, [num]
    add al, '0'
    mov [display], al
    mov eax,4            
    mov ebx,1           
    mov ecx,display      
    mov edx,2 
    int 80h             
    
 
    inc byte [num]
    inc byte [num]
    cmp [num], byte 9
    jng print
       
end:
    mov eax,1           
    mov ebx,0            
    int 80h;
```

Comment: You are missing an `int 80h` before `print`. You are not reading anything.

Comment: The code also appears to contain other issues. For example, assuming that `[num]` will be < 9, when in fact it'll probably be in the `'0'..'9'` range (depending on what you input). And only printing numbers >= num, unlike your description which says that you want to print all even numbers < (or <=) num.